# Cannot read price from url java

Tags: java

I am creating a program that has to take prices of some products from web. I managed to do this for few first products, but then I got a URL that either read with 503 responce from the server or not fully read(tags with price were not included in the output). Here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Test().connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            String url = "https://antoshka.ua/ua/nabir-lakiv-dlya-nigtiv-make-it-real-rusalonka-3-sht6282464.html",
                    proxy = "proxy.mydomain.com",
                    port = "8080";
            URL server = new URL(url);
            Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
            systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxy);
            systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort",port);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            readResponse(in);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void readResponse(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int result = bis.read();
        while(result != -1) {
            byte b = (byte)result;
            buf.write(b);
            result = bis.read();
        }
        System.out.println(buf.toString());
    }
}
```

And here is the url I try to read: https://antoshka.ua/ua/nabir-lakiv-dlya-nigtiv-make-it-real-rusalonka-3-sht6282464.html

Comment: 5xx codes are server error codes. There's nothing you can do about them

Comment: You are doing web scraping on a site that uses some protection against scripted requests. Ethical issues aside, but a usual web browser leaves many fingerprints, which help those guards detect that it is a human driving the client, not some script. One option is to imitate a browser's fingerprints like headers, cookies and so on. Another option could be to use WebDriver to manipulate a browser to do requests. You can try https://selenide.org/ .

Comment: @iTollu you wrote in your comment: _a site that uses some protection against scripted requests_ I'm curious, how do you know that?

Comment: @Abra When I tried to access this site, I was presented a CAPTCHA to prove that I'm a human.

Comment: No, REST API doesn't exist for the primary info. This page is server-rendered. Things like tracking, warehouse availability, recommendations - they use AJAX calls. But not the primary content. Which makes perfect sense SEO-wise and UX-wise. You can explore XHR calls using Chrome Developer Tools, for example.

Comment: If you happen to crawl sketchy sites for commercial purposes, you can’t expect your code to work all the time. Besides, you don’t seem to know how to make HTTP calls anyway, which isn’t by reading and closing streams. There’re literally dozens of HTTP clients, including one shipped with the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse it in incognito mode you will see this

[image: redirect page]

Which mind be the cause of the problem. This also mind mean that this page is protected against bots.

Also waiting for 6 seconds after this command

> server.openConnection();

mind solve your problem

My advise is to use REST API (if exist). I'm not Russian so i cant find this web page's REST API for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
What do you mean "wait for 6 seconds"?
Thread.sleep(6000) or connection.wait(6000)?
Anyway, those two doesn't help.

Comment: I understand logic, but even when I open this link in incognito mode, I can't see redirecting page. Maybe redirecting causes the problem, but why i got part of html on real page, I think i should get small html where wrote "redirecting".

Comment: @Саша Шляхова I don't know what you are trying accomplish here. This type of websites has APIs to let you view their data even my personal page has REST API. If you are not trying to hack them or something you don't need to do it this way. If they don't have a API it means they don't want bots in there system. If they allow you to get that data they will provide it with API and if you try to get data other ways you will always receive errors like this.